# BackgroundTransferService in Windows Phone 8 is not working as expected.

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

As part of a online course I'm taking, I am developing an app to download some images from the internet and then store them in the phone and finally access the images to put them in a listBox.

In a method I have implemented the following:

```
if (BackgroundTransferService.Requests.Count() != 0)
{
    foreach (var item in BackgroundTransferService.Requests)
    {
        item.TransferProgressChanged += item_TransferProgressChanged;
        item.TransferStatusChanged += item_TransferStatusChanged;
    }
}
```

In the Item_TransferStatusChanged is where I check if the download transfer has been completed and then call another method to store the images in the phone, using the IsolatedStorageFile class.

But, the problem is that the download transfer process gets frozen some times. Let say, I'm downloading 10 images, and the proccess gets frozen in the 6 image.

Any clue or help why this is happening would be very helpful

Regards!

Answer (score 2):

There are various scenarios where you must consider before using BackgroundTransferService.

1. Windows phone 8 supports upto 25 download queue per application. In a single time, a single device can download upto 2 files concurrently.So whenever you add something with BackgroundTransferService, it will go into queue. 
   So before adding something into BackgroundTransferService queue, check the BackgroundTransferService.Requests.Count(), it must be less than 25, else Add will throw exception.
2. TransferStatusChanged fires in UI thread. If you are getting any exception , your UI will be sluggish. I think your IsoloatedStorage code is throwing exception.
3. Suppose you started 25 download and before completion, you closed the application. Since you are using this service, all files will be downloaded although application is closed, but next instance whenever you will try to launch and download a file, BackgroundTransferService.Add will fail since BackgroundTransferService has 25 items in queue. Since you closed the application, you didn't get time to remove it from queue. Suggestion is remove these files during launching of the application, or wherever applicable.
   code snippet:

   ```
     public class BackgroundTransferServicesRequest
     {
        static public void RemoveCompletedBackgroundServicesFromQueue()
        {
          foreach (var v in BackgroundTransferService.Requests)
          {
             if (v.TransferStatus == TransferStatus.Completed)
            {
               BackgroundTransferService.Remove(v);
            }
          }
        }
     }
   ```